# Launching app from Google assistant via Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm using Dialogflow to interact with my users (they can ask questions, ask to receive reports etc...) and I would like to launch an Android application when they invoke one the intents I created, is there a way to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Not really.

Longer answer: While you can't have one of your Actions trigger any Android Intent directly, you do have a few options to strongly suggest to a user that they do so. For example:

1. You can use something like Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to trigger a notification/event.
2. If you're relying on the screen of the Android device, you can send a card that includes a URL, and that URL can deep link into your application if you've configured it.

Comment: But then how does "play a song on youtube" trigger youtube app and other such apps?

Comment: @Prisoner, ddalu5 Now it is possible to open app from Google assistant via Dialogflow ?

Comment: It is now probably more difficult than it was before, actually. Tho now you have App Actions which run completely on mobile devices which bring voice control to any app you can currently write. If you have a specific question - go ahead and post it.